# Unable to find Within method using Akka Teskit

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, akka

I see lots of documents referencing the "Within" method on the TestKit.
There appears to be something wrong with my tooling because I'm not able to import that method.

Examples of usage : 
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/testing.html
Should be available as of at least 2.0
http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/testkit/TestKit.html

[image]

Comment: Never mind it appears I can't do something like akka.testKit.TestKit.within(duration) {//code} I must extend test from TestKit

Comment: For the record it appears the above sample showing Testkit usage is broken according to http://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/2072-doc--testkit-sample-is-wrong